# A more efficient way of converting HTML to PDF than XHTMLRenderer+iText

Tags: java, itext

We use iText+XHTMLRenderer to convert large HTML files to PDFs. Today, it managed to hog all the resources in our development environment and render it out of use:

```
This is a jstack dump:
02aaabc585000 nid=0x3af7 runnable [0x00002aaaf0269000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Double.rectCrossings(Path2D.java:1288)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D.intersects(Path2D.java:2290)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D.intersects(Path2D.java:2314)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.intersectsAggregateBounds(BoxCollector.java:90)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:121)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:139)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BoxCollector.collect(BoxCollector.java:46)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.Layer.paint(Layer.java:314)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.paintPage(ITextRenderer.java:384)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.writePDF(ITextRenderer.java:348)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:315)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:246)
```

This is a histo dump:

```
num     instances         bytes  class name
1:       1344539      776639912  [B
2:       1798853      301253344  [C
3:        535059       72768024  org.xhtmlrenderer.render.InlineLayoutBox
4:        762761       52412032  [Ljava.lang.Object;
5:       1519522       48624704  java.lang.String
6:       1149491       45979640  com.someco.p.d
7:        203533       38674984  [I
8:        216490       31313568  &lt;constMethodKlass>
9:        216490       29455216  &lt;methodKlass>
10:        387065       24772160  org.xhtmlrenderer.render.InlineBox
11:         23732       23915216  &lt;constantPoolKlass>
12:        727350       23275200  java.awt.Rectangle
13:        243878       23095936  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
14:        147045       22350840  org.xhtmlrenderer.render.LineBox
15:        667914       21373248  java.util.HashMap$Entry
16:        855194       20524656  java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node
17:         23732       18543256  &lt;instanceKlassKlass>
18:        537890       17212480  org.xhtmlrenderer.css.style.derived.RectPropertySet
19:        688836       16532064  org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.PaintingInfo
20:        688836       16532064  java.awt.Dimension
21:        264061       15254448  &lt;symbolKlass>
22:        268028       15009568  org.xhtmlrenderer.render.InlineText
```

Apparently, this has happened due to a (very, very) large HTML file being converted. It caused us to think - what's better - to block large HTML files from being converted or to find a more efficient means of converting an HTML to PDF *without rendering the HTML to the "screen" first* (which is what XHTMLRednerer does basically).

Googling and reading on the web didn't bring good alternatives. They are all by some sketchy companies we don't know we can trust. Anyone have an alternative in mind?

Comment: I have successfully used [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) in a couple of projects. Worth giving it a try?

Comment: +1 for wkhtmltopdf, works great.

Comment: It's not a Java tool, it's an external binary. There are many binaries out there but we're looking for a pure Java solution.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/

XMLWorker used to ship with iText as HTMLWorker. 
It might not work on html that's overly complex, but try it out.

Current solution is of course to use pdfHTML (an iText7 add-on) in combination with iText7.